# ejs variable inside of an i18next translation package

Tags: javascript, ejs, i18next

the problem i'm having is that in the translation package got something like this:

```
"toBeTranslated":{
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <%=ejsVariable%> consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
}
```

inside the ejs variable is contained "Hello World!!" and in the ejs template i got something like this:

```
<th><%=t("toBeTranslated.text")%></th>
```

and when i go to my webpage the text that i get is exactly the same text:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <%=ejsVariable%> consectetur adipiscing elit, sed..."

and what i really needed is something like this:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **Hello World!!** consectetur adipiscing elit, sed..."

is there any way to make either ejs or i18next to use the value of "<%=ejsVariable%>" instead of writing it as a plain text without taking it out of the translation package?

Answer (score 0):

in order to make ejs recognize the variable you have to do the code like this:

replace the variable <%=ejsVariable%> for **ejsVariable** (this is an i18next variable now)

```
"toBeTranslated":{
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, __ejsVariable__ consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."}
```

and when calling the t function call it like this:

```
t("toBeTranslated.text", {ejsVariable: ejsVariable})
```

this should replace the ejs variable and then with its value replace the i18next variable